# bootstrap mobile collapse nav not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Here's my markup, I followed the bootstrap docs exactly, but I have no idea why the menu doesn't collapse. Any help is welcome

```
<!-- Navigation -->
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">

<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="#" alt="Lundan On The Beat Logo"></a>
</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#home" class="active">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: remove the hash from `id="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"`. The hash is only needed in the `data-target` attribute

Comment: I made that change, still no luck. I have no idea what the problem is

Comment: are you including jQuery before bootstrap.js?

Comment: Yup! I have bootstrap.js included

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/20842/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="#" alt="Lundan On The Beat Logo"></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#home" class="active">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: I missed those closing tags when I copy and pasted the code over, still no luck =(